# ControlParameter - Syntax error: Missing operand after 'Where' operator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I want to search by a dropdown value. I am using ControlParameters in this instance and want to search by the dropdown the user selects. Is it possible using ControlParameters?  I have put the error below but the Error i get is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <p>Show all employees with the following title:</p>

            <asp:SqlDataSource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mySQLConnectionString%>"
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tblmovie"
                FilterExpression="MovieID='{0}' or MovieName Like '%'{1}'%' and {2} Like '%'{3}'%'">
                <FilterParameters>
                      <asp:ControlParameter Name="MovieID"  ControlId="DropDownList1" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
                      <asp:ControlParameter Name="MovieName" ControlId="DropDownList2" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>                         
                      <asp:ControlParameter Name="Search" ControlId="DropDownList3" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>         
                      <asp:ControlParameter Name="Search1" ControlId="txtSearch" PropertyName="text" Type="String"/>  
                </FilterParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

<table style="width: 650px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" >
<tr>

<td style="width: 150px;">
Movie ID
 <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="888">Please Select...</asp:ListItem>            
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
</td>
<td style="width: 150px;">
Movie Name
 <asp:DropDownList
                id="DropDownList2"
                runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="True">    
                 <asp:ListItem Value="999">Please Select...</asp:ListItem>              
                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
</td>

<td style="width: 150px;">
Search
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
</td>
<td style="width: 150px;">
Where
<asp:DropDownList  id="DropDownList3" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                <asp:ListItem>Please Select...</asp:ListItem>            
                <asp:ListItem>MovieName</asp:ListItem>          
                <asp:ListItem>MovieID</asp:ListItem>            
                <asp:ListItem>Oscars</asp:ListItem>                      
</asp:DropDownList>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="4">
<p>
</p>
<p></p>
</td></tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="4">
            <asp:GridView  id="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Width="600px">
                <columns>                 
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Movie Name" DataField="MovieName"  />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MovieID" DataField="MovieID" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Release Date" DataField="ReleaseDate" />
                     <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Oscars" DataField="Oscars" />
                </columns>
            </asp:GridView>
   </td>
   </tr>     
   </table>  
 </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 FilterExpression="MovieID={0} or MovieName Like '%{1}%' or Oscars={2}  Where {3} Like '% txtSearch.text %'">
```

looks weird to me.

FilterExpression="MovieID={0} or MovieName Like '%{1}%' or Oscars={2}  **Where** {3} Like '% txtSearch.text %'">

I don't think the word "Where" should be in there?  Should it be an "AND" or an "OR"?

To me it seems like there is an implicit (one that you don't have to type) "WHERE" at the beginning of the filter expression.

Comment: Okay so I am getting an error Syntax error: Missing operand after '999' operator. I have changed the value for {0} to 888 so I know it is at the point {0} and {1} connect now...

Comment: What is your current code?  Repost.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to effectively have a where statement (i.e. using the AND in this case) where the user selects the column they are to search i.e. Firstname/LastName. I have reported my code as it stands. The other solution I have looked at is SessionParameters. I have both types of code working until I try to make the columnname a variable.

Comment: 999 seems to be coming from:  <asp:ListItem Value="999">Please Select...</asp:ListItem>  

This looks like the spot where you are supposed to have column names?  If you have SQL that is saying " and 999 like '%...%' that is going to be a problem.